# What does bootstrapping in angular2 do?

Tags: angular

I have been looking around the internet and I have to admit that I have not found an answer that I can understand.
I have been working with angular1 for some time and while I may have done the actual process of bootstrapping I do not know that it was called that.

From wiki

> In general parlance, bootstrapping usually refers to a self-starting process that is supposed to proceed without external input.

- Do I need to bootstrap more than once in my application?
- Am I allowed to use bootstrap more than once?
- What are some good practices regarding bootstrapping?
- What is usually bootstrapped? (I see that you boostrap location strategy. Can you use both?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In short, calling the `bootstrap` allows to attach the main component of your Angular2 to an HTML element in the main web page and execute actually the Angular2 application. In such applications, you only need to call it once.

When Angular calls the `bootstrap` function, it reads the main component metadata, finds its selector, locates an element tag with the name provided in the main component selector and loads the application between those tags.

You can notice that bootstrapping an Angular application is platform-specific (browser, mobile device...). That's why this function isn't located in the `angular2/core` package...

I think you should have a look at this page: https://angular.io/guide/quickstart#serve.

Comment: In Angular2, the main component of your application is bootstrapped (first parameter of the `bootstrap` method). You can also define the providers for the whole application (application level).

Comment: A classical Angular2 component that you'll use as main component of your application... It can include other components, define routing, ...

Comment: "bootstrap allows to take control of the main web page" -- it doesn't have to take control of the whole page, or eventhe main page.  Angular can coexist with other frameworks (like Angular 1!).

Answer (score 1):

Do I need to bootstrap more than once in my application?

No. Typically, you bootstrap once for an angular app.  Usually it is done by adding an ngApp directive to your html:

```
<body ng-app="app">
```

And then writing script to bootstrap the module:

```
app.module('app',[]);
```

Am I allowed to use bootstrap more than once?

Yes. If you want multiple bootstrapped modules, you'll need to call angular.bootstrap instead of placing an ngApp directive in the HTML.

What are some good practices regarding bootstrapping?

Generally, prefer bootstrapping once.